# Codename One : check if phone is in silence mode

Tags: codenameone

I would like my app not to vibrate if the phone is in silence mode. However I could not find any method in Display that tell you if the phone is in silence mode.

Is it possible and if so how can I do ?

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work but when you play media you can query the volume and it might return 0. I would instead both play the media and vibrate which should solve that.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I will try your suggestion but I think the device can be in silence mode (no ring, no vibration) with media sound level higher than 0.

Comment: It probably can, I'm not sure if there is a way to detect that.